# Pubmed API returns less results than web interface

Tags: pubmed, pubmed-api

I'm trying to access Pubmed results via R using their API, but I consistently get fewer results than what the same query achieves when used with the web interface. By digging in the output I noticed that the problem lays in a different query translation between the two access methods.

I am using the `rentrez` package, but the results I get are the same also with other related rpackages, so I guess it's related to the API itself.

here's the code to reproduce the results:

```
install.packages('rentrez')

rentrez::entrez_search(db="pubmed", term = '((model OR models OR modeling OR network OR networks) AND (dissemination OR transmission OR spread OR diffusion) AND (nosocomial OR hospital OR "long-term-care" OR "long term care" OR "longterm care" OR "long-term care" OR "hospital acquired" OR "healtcare associated") AND (infection OR resistance OR resistant)) AND (2010[PDAT]:2020[PDAT])')$count

[1] 7157
```

The same query on https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ returns 9263 results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you still need this now. Just in case someone else has the same problem.
I had the same issue as you did and I found something might be useful from a GitHub issue.
It seems that the API service needs to be updated to match the new web service, but it's been a year now and still no promising announcement has been made by the official.
An alternative is provided by the easyPubMed author. Hope this is what you were looking for.

[easyPubMed Issue](https://github.com/dami82/easyPubMed/issues/4)

Comment: Thanks! I guess it was a Pubmed itself problem. Unfortunately their workaround doesn't really fit the workflow I built...